# How to handle short coding sessions?

Tags: time

I'm working on some pet projects and generally I sit around my personal computer about 22:30 or 23:00 to code. But since I try to sleep about 24:00 I don't start coding and ending up reading articles, playing some games etc.

I don't feel like I can write decent code in an hour, because the project is quite big and I don't want to randomly or carelessly hack it. Even though I use TDD, most of the time stuff I'm doing is not straight forward which requires lots of testing before getting it right.

What's your approach to these kind of issues? Do you just code later when you got enough time or do you have a different approach which allows you to code just for 30 minutes and continue later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally don't write lots of code until i have the time to do it. The reason is that for me to get effective takes focus and that takes a bit of time to be correctly focused. That said those 30min slots are great for

- Writing more tests: nothing like trying to get to 100% code coverage, and it's not a big waste since you are investing
- Research: I spend lots of time reading blogs, looking for frameworks I can use or tools. Spending 30min finding a framework that does 80% of a feature you need is much better than spending hours trying to code it. The other factor to this is that if you implement the framework and you find it is a bad fit you are better educated in the needs which means your development will be smoother.

Answer (score 1):

Well my first thought was "use unit testing", but then I read you are already using this. But I still think it's the solution to your program.

Try to make your tests as small as possible and use the "1 assert per unit test" rule to create small atomic tests. You should be able to fix several of these small tests in a 30-minute session.

Comment: what last night happened was implementing a plugin support which requires massive changes and breaks the build, maybe I should leave these to longer sessions and sticking with small changes for short sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things you could try:

- Don't sit near the computer. Instead, take a large piece of paper and go somewhere quiet. Think about what you want to accomplish. Write down interface ideas, detailed implementation. Make a list of questions you need to solve before you can go on.
- Take off a week and code away. The ratio of getting-into-flow over flow-time is just too bad for 30 minutes.
- Keep a log about what you do instead of coding. Observe your emotional state.
- Go to bed early and try to have your pet coding session very early in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

A small tip (that I use at work too) is to stop coding in the middle of something, with an obvious big red compile error waiting.

The next time you start working, the error will actually help you to remember what on earth you were doing.

While you are working on the small problem, the big picture clears up and then you can continue designing.

Answer (score 0):

Developing with such short times is difficult, but you can still get something of that time. Unit testing is one. Writing down the interface of a class is another. While coding the real stuff will take much more time, these tasks are essentially a no-brainer, and they are just an exercise in typing.

So, my suggestion is: focus on small tasks that do not require thinking and concentration, and can be completed in the timespan you have.

Answer (score 0):

Never worked for me, pet projects are usually too interesting and I end up working to late hours of the night or through a weekend.

I would suggest reconsidering your priorities - if all the time you have available is one hour late at night, maybe it's better to spend it on games, articles etc. Or just hanging out. When you have a bit more time, say a lazy Sunday, spend all the time at once and actually get the sense of accomplishing something that pet projects are supposed to give.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do with my personal projects outside of work:

- 1) I try to give myself a good map of my project by planning it out on paper.  I diagram all of my objects, data structures, and/or SQL tables and determine what basic functions and interactions between those components are necessary.  I may write some actual code during this phase if the solution is obvious, but typically not.
- 2) Once the big picture is in place, I prioritize the most basic and critical elements.  I also try to figure out which parts will be easier to write than others.
- 3) After priorities have been set I start working on the easiest and most critical parts first and work gradually towards the more complex and less important components.  Breaking each task down into smaller parts tends to help.  For example, I may design a database table first and the next day create a data interface class that controls interactions with that table.
- 4) Unit testing really helps me feel a sense of accomplishment, even if 30 minutes of effort only results in a few quality lines code.
- 5) Keep a change log, even if it isn't very detailed.  I've found my change logs to be invaluable if I work on a big project in many short spurts over an extended period of time.

Those steps right there help me the most.  In the end I am able to identify small chuncks of the project that can typically be completed in about 30-60 minutes.  Of course, as a project develops, I usually have to re-evaluate something and go back to the beginning for a while when I discover I left something out of the planning phases.  Sometimes I need to go a bit farther and give myself a time line with some deadlines and make sure I celebrate milestones with a personal reward.  If you have a tendency of staying up till the wee hours of the morning, something I struggle with, I also suggest giving yourself a coding curfew as well.  I also try to make sure my "coding computer" doesn't have many distractions on it, such as games.

Answer (score 0):

There's always one more bug. If not, there's one more neat feature you can add, and THAT will add more bugs. Which is one reason why I think that the use of the phrase "All you have to do..." by anyone in (or using) IT should be a hanging offense.

I can cut down on how long my coding sessions last by doing trivial things, thinking things out while away from the keyboard (the shower is best - or while in bed at 4 a.m.) and by using lightweight environments such as script languages, but "quick" coding sessions are something I long ago gave up hope on.

Just shifting mental gears into the coding mode takes time, picking up the threads of where I was before takes time, discovering that my "quick and easy solution" was neither of the above takes time. *Fixing* my "quick and easy solution takes time, debugging - more time, and so forth.